# Xamarin Make Tabs Expand Full Width

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, tabs

How can I get these tabs to expand full width?

```
<TabbedPage.Children>
        <me:SalesLinesTabView Title="Tab 1"/>
        <me:CreditLinesTabView Title="Tab 2"/>
</TabbedPage.Children>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could change the `tabModel` in your `Tabbar.xml` in your Android project.

change

```
app:tabMode="scrollable"
```

to

```
app:tabMode="fixed"
```

Comment: Where  Tabbar.xml in is (your Android project)/Resources/layout

Comment: I did this but the tabs are still the same size.

Comment: @christinapapaaa11 What's your XF version ?

Comment: @christinapapaaa11 And you could try to add  `app:tabMaxWidth="0dp` to the TabLayout